# Java Printf Alignment Output

Tags: java

All I would like to know what's wrong with this is why do things get pushed to the right when there is 3 numbers a decimal point and a decimal. Why isn't this being aligned? I've had this problem with other code, even copied someones code that should've displayed decimal points aligning in a column but it always doesn't align.  Please ignore everything above "_________________________________" line, I know it's not aligned with that, i just want to know why it's doing what it's doing below that line. (why mis aligning everything by pushing top 3 rows to the right)

**Book Answer's Console Result in MY eclipse console**

[image: watf]

**What the actual answer is supposed to look like according to book answer result**

[image: watg]

**Books Answer Code**

```
package Ch5_Methods;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testch5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s|    %-15s%-15s\n","Celsius","Fahrenheit","Fahrenheit","Celsius");
      System.out.println( String.format("%62s"," ").replace(' ', '-') );

      for (int c = 40, f = 120  ; c >=31; c--, f-=10) {

       System.out.printf("%-15.1f%-15.1f|    %-15.1f%-15.2f\n",(float)c,celsiusToFahrenheit(c),(float)f, fahrenheitToCelsius(f));

      }


     }

     /** Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit */
     public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {
      return (9.0 / 5) * celsius + 32;
     }

     /** Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius */
     public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
      return (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);

    }




}
```

I cannot figure out how to align the code, I've tried formatting different ways with printf, I'm still a beginner and i'm sure there is an easier way to do this, but i'm trying to accomplish this having only covered methods, loops, if/else, formatting and other basic stuff.

Comment: If you want to ask about output and alignment, make sure your question shows your intent. Please [edit] your question and improve it.

Comment: You can make your code output text with the correct amount of space to align things, but it won't look right if your console is using a variable width font. Switch your console to a monospaced font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that periods take up less space than the other characters. You need to switch to a mono spaced font. Eclipse has some documentation for how to do that [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm).

You can see [here](http://goo.gl/mXnn6a) that it works with a mono spaced font.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the link, this solved my problem, It wasn't anything wrong with the code it was just different fonts. I switched to Courier font, I was on sequoia font.